# certbot-auto (2021) for Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo) and nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, certbot

I checked my ec2 system version:

```
cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)


cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

The new version of [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) seems to require [snapd](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snapd) to install, but `Amazon Linux release 2` does not seem to support the installation of snapd.

```
sudo yum install snapd
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                               | 3.7 kB     00:00
No package snapd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I did not see the relevant system version in the installation [teaching](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snapd) of snapd:
[image]

I don’t know if `Amazon Linux release 2` should be classified in [CentOS](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel7-nginx)?
`Amazon Linux release 2` is not included in the options, nor did I see the related words.

[image]

`Epel-release` and `dnf` are mentioned in the `CentOS` teaching, but they don’t seem to support installation.
[image]

Or ec2 just used other methods to install certbot?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm going down a similar path because the epel repo certbot is too old to use `preferred-chain` arg which is needed now to bypass the expired cert from sep 30th...

Answer (score 0):

AWS has another way to install certbot, instructions are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#letsencrypt

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using snap and install Certbot with Pip.

From the [official Certobot documentation:](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#alternative-2-pip)

1. `sudo dnf install python3 augeas-libs`
2. remove any previous installation of Certbot
3. `sudo python3 -m venv /opt/certbot/ && sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install --upgrade pip`
4. `sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install certbot certbot-nginx`
5. `sudo ln -s /opt/certbot/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot`

There you go